# How to execute PHP from TinyWeb

Tags: php, webserver

How do I set up my system to get [TinyWeb](http://www.ritlabs.com/en/products/tinyweb/features.php) to execute PHP scripts?

Mongoose asked me to specify the location of `php-cgi.exe`, but I'm not sure how to do this for TinyWeb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. I came across this site: http://itsecuritylab.eu/index.php/2010/09/24/tinyweb-pocket-size-portable-web-server-with-cgi-and-php-support/

Downloaded the one that came with PHP included and simply unpacked it.

When I tried to access the provided `index.php` script on

`localhost:81/index.php`

the following error occured

`the procedure entry point php_checkuid could not be located in the dynamic link library php5.dll`

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154016/entry-point-error-when-running-php-script-from-command-line), where one of the answers talks about old PHP installations in the environment variables.

I realized that there was an older version of PHP, went and deleted it and replaced it with the latest version, and the script ran successfully with

`TinyWeb is successfully running PHP 5.5.11 :-)`

Removing `index.html` from the `wwwroot` folder, I assumed `index.php` would be run as the default, though the server just returned "Forbidden". This is an issue, but in any case I just needed something simple to host PHP scripts so it is ok.

Comment: the link is no longer working :(